# "Undo" canvas transformations for writing text

Tags: javascript, canvas, transformation

When applying a transformation with canvas, the resulting text is also (obviously) transformed. Is there a way to prevent certain transformations, such as reflection, of affecting text?

For example, I set a global transformation matrix so the Y-axis points upwards, X-axis to the right, and the `(0, 0)` point is in the center of the screen (what you'd expect of a mathematical coordinate system).

However, this also makes the text upside-down.

```js
const size = 200;

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, size / 2, size / 2);

const triangle = [
  {x: -70, y: -70, label: 'A'},
  {x:  70, y: -70, label: 'B'},
  {x:   0, y:  70, label: 'C'},
];

// draw lines  
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.moveTo(triangle[2].x, triangle[2].y);
triangle.forEach(v => ctx.lineTo(v.x, v.y));
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
  
// draw labels
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.font = '24px Arial';
triangle.forEach(v => ctx.fillText(v.label, v.x, v.y - 8));
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Is there a "smart" way to get the text in "correct" orientation, apart from manually resetting transformation matrices?

Comment: Here is a more general example for the bounty, where I have not only flipped the y axis, but also have a zoom and translation. How would one draw the text next to the points in the correct orientation and scale? https://jsfiddle.net/7ryfwvfm/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To build off of Tai's answer, which is fantastic, you might want to consider the following:

```js
    const size = 200;

    const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
    canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Create a custom fillText funciton that flips the canvas, draws the text, and then flips it back
    ctx.fillText = function(text, x, y) {
      this.save();       // Save the current canvas state
      this.scale(1, -1); // Flip to draw the text
      this.fillText.dummyCtx.fillText.call(this, text, x, -y); // Draw the text, invert y to get coordinate right
      this.restore();    // Restore the initial canvas state
    }
    // Create a dummy canvas context to use as a source for the original fillText function
    ctx.fillText.dummyCtx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, size / 2, size / 2);

    const triangle = [
      {x: -70, y: -70, label: 'A'},
      {x:  70, y: -70, label: 'B'},
      {x:   0, y:  70, label: 'C'},
    ];

    // draw lines  
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo(triangle[2].x, triangle[2].y);
    triangle.forEach(v => ctx.lineTo(v.x, v.y));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
      
    // draw labels
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = '24px Arial';
    // For this particular example, multiplying x and y by small factors >1 offsets the labels from the triangle vertices
    triangle.forEach(v => ctx.fillText(v.label, 1.2*v.x, 1.1*v.y));
```

The above is useful if for your real application, you'll be going back and forth between drawing non-text objects and drawing text and don't want to have to remember to flip the canvas back and forth. (It's not a huge problem in the current example, because you draw the triangle and then draw all the text, so you only need one flip. But if you have in mind a different application that's more complex, that could be an annoyance.) In the above example, I've replaced the fillText method with a custom method that flips the canvas, draws the text, and then flips it back again so that you don't have to do it manually every time you want to draw text.

The result:

[image]

If you don't like overriding the default `fillText`, then obviously you can just create a method with a new name; that way you could also avoid creating the dummy context and just use `this.fillText` within your custom method.

EDIT: The above approach also works with arbitrary zoom and translation. `scale(1, -1)` simply reflects the canvas over the x-axis: after this transformation, a point that was at (x, y) will now be at (x, -y). This is true regardless of translation and zoom. If you want the text to remain a constant size regardless of zoom, then you just have to scale the font size by zoom. For example:

```html
<html>
<body>
 <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</body>

<script>

 const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var framesPerSec = 100;
 var msBetweenFrames = 1000/framesPerSec;
 ctx.font = '12px Arial';

 function getRandomCamera() {
  return {x: ((Math.random() > 0.5) ? -1 : 1) * Math.random()*5,
       y: ((Math.random() > 0.5) ? -1 : 1) * Math.random()*5+5,
       zoom: Math.random()*20+0.1,
    };
 }

 var camera = getRandomCamera();
 moveCamera();

 function moveCamera() {
  var newCamera = getRandomCamera();
  var transitionFrames = Math.random()*500+100;
  var animationTime = transitionFrames*msBetweenFrames;

  var cameraSteps = { x: (newCamera.x-camera.x)/transitionFrames,
          y: (newCamera.y-camera.y)/transitionFrames,
          zoom: (newCamera.zoom-camera.zoom)/transitionFrames };
  
  for (var t=0; t<animationTime; t+=msBetweenFrames) {
   window.setTimeout(updateCanvas, t);
  }
  window.setTimeout(moveCamera, animationTime);

  function updateCanvas() {
   camera.x += cameraSteps.x;
   camera.y += cameraSteps.y;
   camera.zoom += cameraSteps.zoom;
   redrawCanvas();
  }
 }

 ctx.drawText = function(text, x, y) {
  this.save();
  this.transform(1 / camera.zoom, 0, 0, -1 / camera.zoom, x, y);
  this.fillText(text, 0, 0);
  this.restore();
 }

 function redrawCanvas() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2 - (camera.x * camera.zoom),
              canvas.height / 2 + (camera.y * camera.zoom));
  ctx.scale(camera.zoom, -camera.zoom);

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(5, i * 2, .5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.drawText(i, 7, i*2-0.5);
      ctx.fill();
  }

  ctx.restore();
 }

</script>

</html>
```

EDIT: Modified text scaling method based on suggestion by Blindman67. Also improved demo by making camera motion gradual.

Comment: Added a more general example I want explained as a comment to the question.

Comment: The same general approach should work even for your more general case. See the added example in my edit above.

Comment: your font scaling method will fail when the px size get too small also some browsers drop the fractions for canvas font sizes plus resizing a font can be slower than just scaling the font. Your drawText function will be more efficient (and reliable) as follows `c.save(); c.setTransform(1 / camera.zoom, 0, 0, -1 / camera.zoom, x, -y); c.fillText(text, 0, 0); c.restore();` and will not fail when zoom is large and a lot faster if the zoom or font is changing between calls.

Comment: @Blindman67, thanks! Your way is clearly better. I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example with arbitrary translation and zoom. Awarded to bounty to you.

Answer (score 7):

My solution is rotate the canvas and then draw the text.

```
ctx.scale(1,-1); // rotate the canvas
triangle.forEach(v => {
ctx.fillText(v.label, v.x, -v.y + 25); // draw with a bit adapt position
});
```

Hope that helps :)

```js
const size = 200;

const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
canvas.width = canvas.height = size;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, -1, size / 2, size / 2);

const triangle = [
  {x: -70, y: -70, label: 'A'},
  {x:  70, y: -70, label: 'B'},
  {x:   0, y:  70, label: 'C'},
];

// draw lines  

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.moveTo(triangle[2].x, triangle[2].y);
triangle.forEach(v => ctx.lineTo(v.x, v.y));
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

// draw labels
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.font = '24px Arial';
ctx.scale(1,-1);
triangle.forEach(v => {
ctx.fillText(v.label, v.x, -v.y + 25);
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Added a more general example I want explained as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with an approach that stores the "state" of your drawing without the actual pixels, and defines a `draw` method that can render this state at any point.

You'll have to implement your own `scale` and `translate` methods for your points, but I think it's worth it in the end.

So, in bullets:

- Store a list of "things to draw" (points with labels)
- Expose `scale` and `translate` methods that modify these "things"
- Expose a `draw` method that renders these "things"

As an example, I've created a class called `Figure` that shows a 1.0 implementation of these features. I create a new instance that references a canvas. I then add points to it by passing an `x`, `y` and a `label`. `scale` and `transform` update these points' `x` and `y` properties. `draw` loops through the points to a) draw the "dot", and b) draw the label.

```js
const Figure = function(canvas) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const origin = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
  };
  const shift = p => Object.assign(p, {
    x: origin.x + p.x,
    y: origin.y - p.y
  });

  let points = [];

  this.addPoint = (x, y, label) => {
    points = points.concat({
      x,
      y,
      label
    });
  }

  this.translate = (tx, ty) => {
    points = points.map(
      p => Object.assign(p, {
        x: p.x + tx,
        y: p.y + ty
      })
    );
  };

  this.scale = (sx, sy) => {
    points = points.map(
      p => Object.assign(p, {
        x: p.x * sx,
        y: p.y * sy
      })
    );
  };

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();

    const sPoints = points.map(shift);

    sPoints.forEach(p => drawDot(ctx, 5, p.x, p.y));
    sPoints.forEach(p => drawLabel(ctx, p.label, p.x + 5, p.y));

    ctx.fill();
  }
}

const init = () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const fig = new Figure(canvas);

  // Generate some test data
  for (let i = 0, labels = "ABCD"; i < labels.length; i += 1) {
    fig.addPoint(i * 3, (i + 1) * 10, labels[i]);
  }

  const sX = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".js-scaleX").value);
  const sY = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".js-scaleY").value);
  const tX = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".js-transX").value);
  const tY = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".js-transY").value);

  fig.scale(sX, sY);
  fig.translate(tX, tY);
  fig.draw();
}

Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll("input"))
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("change", init));

init();



// Utilities for drawing
function drawDot(ctx, d, x, y) {
  ctx.arc(x, y, d / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}

function drawLabel(ctx, label, x, y) {
  ctx.fillText(label, x, y);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #efefef;
  margin: 1rem;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Scales first, translates second (hard coded, can be changed)
  </p>
  <label>Scale x <input type="number" class="js-scaleX" value="1"></label>
  <label>Scale y <input type="number" class="js-scaleY" value="1"></label>
  <br/>
  <label>Translate x <input type="number" class="js-transX" value="0"></label>
  <label>translate y <input type="number" class="js-transY" value="0"></label>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

*Note: use the inputs for an example of how this works. I've chosen to "commit" the changes from scale and translate immediately, so order matters! You might want to press full-screen to get both canvas and inputs in to view.*

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```
  var x = 100;
  var y = 100;
  var pixelRatio = 2;
  var transform = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "k": 1}

  context.save();
  context.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0.0, 0.0, pixelRatio, 0.0, 0.0);
  context.translate(transform.x, 0);
  context.scale(transform.k, 1);

  context.save();
  // get Transformed Point
  var context_transform = context.getTransform();
  var pt = context_transform.transformPoint({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });

  // Reset previous transforms
  context.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0.0, 0.0, pixelRatio, -pt.x, -pt.y);
  

  // draw with the values as usual
  context.textAlign = "left";
  context.font = "14px Arial";
  context.fillText("Hello", pt.x, pt.y);
  context.restore();

  context.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to the accepted answer to make it more performant.  Doing ctx.save/restore backs up and restores the entire context.  This is not necessary in this situation.  Also, if you alternate between flipping the y axis and not (e.g. creating a reusable library), you can represent this in a simple way.

Instead of:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(1, -1);
ctx.strokeText(text, x, -y);
ctx.restore();
```

You can do:

```
// Somewhere in your library
let flipy = -1; // If not flipping y then set to 1

// To draw text
ctx.scale(1, flipy);                // If flipy is 1 then no effect
ctx.strokeText(text, x, y * flipy); // If flipy is 1 then keep current y
ctx.scale(1, flipy);                // Undo the previous flip
```

This only changes and restores the transformation matrix instead of the entire context.